# WSO2 Micro-integrator

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

Can you help me please. I downloaded WSO2 micro-integrator, set JAVA_HOME Java JDK 17 and when I want to start it I got this error:

```
- INFO {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Overriding files in configuration directory C:\PROGRA~1\WSO2MI~1\bin\..
- FATAL {org.wso2.micro.integrator.server.Main} - Error while performing configuration changes org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParserException: Error while creating new directory C:\PROGRA~1\WSO2MI~1\bin\..\backup\conf\axis2\axis2.xml
    at org.wso2.config.mapper.util.FileUtils.writeFile(FileUtils.java:74) ~[config-mapper-1.0.20.jar:1.0.20]
    at org.wso2.config.mapper.util.FileUtils.writeDirectory(FileUtils.java:101) ~[config-mapper-1.0.20.jar:1.0.20]
    at org.wso2.config.mapper.util.FileUtils.writeDirectory(FileUtils.java:138) ~[config-mapper-1.0.20.jar:1.0.20]
    at org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser.backupConfigurations(ConfigParser.java:178) ~[config-mapper-1.0.20.jar:1.0.20]
    at org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser.deployAndStoreMetadata(ConfigParser.java:190) ~[config-mapper-1.0.20.jar:1.0.20]
    at org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:137) ~[config-mapper-1.0.20.jar:1.0.20]
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.server.Main.handleConfiguration(Main.java:385) ~[org.wso2.micro.integrator.server-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.server.Main.main(Main.java:118) ~[org.wso2.micro.integrator.server-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:70) ~[org.wso2.micro.integrator.bootstrap-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:51) ~[org.wso2.micro.integrator.bootstrap-4.2.0.jar:4.2.0]
```

What I do wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you install Micro Integrator? Can you add the full path of the installation location?

Comment: I'm unzip Micro Integrator to 'C:\Program Files\wso2mi' folder

Answer (score 0):

Having spaces in the installation path can cause issues with WSO2 products. The directory `Program Files` has a space in-between. So try moving the server installation to a location where each directory in the path doesn't have any spaces. For example, `C:\wso2\wso2mi`